# Selenium Webdirver

Tags: python, selenium

when I use Selenium and scrapy to spider  information developed by dymanic JS.I use the webdriver.PhantomJS  .But I found such debug information in the cmd window

selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:57000/wd/hub/session/26c385f0-d448-11e5-80bb-7575f0e930be/url

there will be many of them and they slowed my spider.How can I turn off it.I only want to speed up the spider.

Answer (score 0):

This is the selenium logging and *logging itself does not slow things down*. The need to fire up and automate a real browser (even headless) is what slowing the web-scraping process.

If you want not to see the INFO and DEBUG messages, change the logging level to WARNING:

```
import logging

selenium_logger = logging.getLogger('selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection')
selenium_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Put this into `settings.py` of your Scrapy project.

Comment: After I change thenlogging level.The operationwill still work.I Also Can not speed up the spider.In your word,The operation can not be turned off????????